# How to append text in existing XML node without having to use UPDATEXML?

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I am trying to update my xml data but it only allows me to update up to 4000 characters. I decided to split them up and update 1000-1000 characters in a loop, therefore I will be needing to append the xml instead of updating the whole thing.

here's my code:

first I split the given data:

```
String[] mydata=mydata.split("(?<=\\G.{1000})")
```

then I use updatexml in a loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<comments.length; i++){
        select = "update datadocumentxml d\n" +
                    "   set d.datadocumentxml = updatexml(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/CB_Data/Example/@Comment', ?)\n" + 
        //          "                                   .getClobVal(),\n" + 
                    "                                   
                    " where d.processengineguid = fnguidjava2raw(?)\n" + 
                    "   and d.datadocumentid = 'CB_Data'";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);
                    ps.setString(1,comment);

        //ps.setString(1,comments[i]);
        ps.setString(2,processid);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

So basically I am trying to update the data 1000 by each time, but it overwrites since I am using updatexml.

when I run this, if the data is 1500 characters, it will only display the last 500 characters, and that's quite obvious. but is there a way to update the xml without overwriting the previous data? so I can 'append' data each time in a loop? sorry if I am being unclear, this is my first question here.

Comment: hi. can you provide a sample xml and a sample change you want to make to it? KR

Comment: @Peter hi, so for example if `/CB_Data/Example/@Comment='com1'`  before the update, I want to 'append' 'com2' so my final xml node would be `/CB_Data/Example/@Comment='com1 com2`'

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem with the 4000 char limitation as I could not believe for it to be the case - and in fact I did not run into this limitation (12.1.0.2). See below, this code should be your solution already as well:

```
create table tst (datadocumentxml clob);
insert into tst values ('<root>');
-- this adds a little over 500 chars, run this 10 times
update tst set datadocumentxml = datadocumentxml || '<send>whistle</send>
  <back>
    <travel>giant</travel>
    <son>844851954</son>
    <may>-2056575796.4096966</may>
    <larger>
      <flow>1293043813</flow>
      <since>plastic</since>
      <orbit>please</orbit>
      <won>angle</won>
      <power>-704746039</power>
      <molecular>420367029</molecular>
    </larger>
    <rocky>727548108</rocky>
    <youth>-761804169.1209936</youth>
  </back>
  <tin>attention</tin>
  <suddenly>southern</suddenly>
  <similar>language</similar>
  <rabbit>captain</rabbit>';
-- this adds your example now  
update tst set datadocumentxml = datadocumentxml || '<CB_Data><Example Comment = "com1">example text</Example></CB_Data>';
-- before the next line add 10 times the 500 lines again
-- now we add the closing tag
update tst set datadocumentxml = datadocumentxml || '</root>';
commit;

-- this update does now work for me to append 'com2' to the existing comment
update tst d set d.datadocumentxml = updatexml(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/root/CB_Data/Example/@Comment', 
(select extractvalue(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/root/CB_Data/Example/@Comment') from tst d)
||' '||'com2').getclobval();

select * from tst;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I get  `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long` error after reach 4000 symbols.
So I decided to store that string in a clob before updating, and it worked, clob allows me to update 20k+ characters in one update. but I came across this weird problem. Updating latin characters, symbols was not a problem. But I come from Georgia (Republic of) and it ALWAYS fails to update Georgian characters. which are like აბგ (abc). I tried with Russian characters and it worked perfectly, it only has problem with Georgian characters..

Comment: this is the first time you mentioned that this is about character sets :-) anyway, can you provide a full example of the xml and the update that fails?

Comment: `"update datadocumentxml d\n" +
                    "   set d.datadocumentxml = updatexml(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/Comments/@Comment', ?)\n" + 
                    "                                   .getClobVal(),\n" + 

                    " where d.processengineguid = fnguidjava2raw(?)\n" + 
                    "   and d.datadocumentid = 'Comments'";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);

        ps.setClob(1,clob);
        ps.setString(2,processid);
        rs = ps.executeQuery(); `

so this update works perfectly on english characters, the only prob is georgian ones.

Comment: I get different errors whenever I try to update using Georgian letters:

`ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error` or 
`java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket`

Comment: what if you do `select 'აბგ' from dual`? same error?

Comment: no, usually pl/sql developer can't read query results that are in Georgian unless I go to tools and change the font, then I can read it.  I do think it has something to do with character sets. and by the way, I hope this helps - when string allowed me to update 4000 Latin letters, I was only able to update third of that amount (1333) of Georgian letters, so it kinda takes more bytes too.

Updating using String works perfectly, but I need more than 1333 Georgian characters, that's why I changed it to clob, but clob fails to update them. It works perfectly on other characters though..

Comment: I did, same thing - English characters work fine, I can only update up to dozen Georgian characters and when I try to update a bit more it gives me error: 
`ORA-00600 internal error code, arguments:....`